# HTACCESS complicated query

Tags: .htaccess

Hey! I have this question about HTACCESS.

I know how to do a 301 from all lowercase to all uppercase and vice versa but I'm confused with this one.

I want to do a 301 redirect via HTaccess. The pages I have look like www.mysite.com/James or www.mysite.com/Paul

I want pages like www.mysite.com/JAMES or www.mysite.com/james or www.mysite.com/jAmES to 301 redirect to www.mysite.com/James (proper case).. any idea how to do this please?

Comment: Does this apply to *any* directory name, or do you have a list of names somewhere? If so, where? Please give more information.

Comment: Hey Pekka - Thanks for replying. I've done this SEO friendly thing. Originally, a page that looked like mysite.com/product.php?id=1 now looks like mysite.com/James . I've used the following to do this: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ destination.php?id=$1&tab=$2

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want something like this, although as Pekka mentioned it's a bit difficult to know for sure without more detail:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-Z][a-z]+$
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+)$ http://www.example.com/${toupper:$1}${tolower:$2} [L,R]
```

Keep in mind that you have to actually have the `toupper` and `tolower` maps defined in your server's configuration, which is not possible if you don't have control over the server or your virtual host definition.

`httpd.conf` or a virtual host:

```
RewriteMap toupper int:toupper
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
```

As a side note, I'm fairly confused why `mod_rewrite`'s internal map functions have to be explicitly declared, but that's what the code says (and what the documentation fails to mention), so there you go.

**Edit**: To capitalize one or more words in a space-delimited string, we can do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1   (.*)((?:\s|\A)[A-Za-z])([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteCond $1 !^(\s?[A-Z][a-z]+)+$
RewriteRule /?(.*) %1 [N,E=CC_URL:${toupper:%2}${tolower:%3}%{ENV:CC_URL}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:CC_URL} !=""
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/$0%{ENV:CC_URL} [L,R]
```

I'd thoroughly test this one out before letting it run in the wild though. I'm fairly certain it should work fine, but since there's the possibility that it could cause an infinite loop and send one of your `httpd` children spiraling out of control...use with caution.

**Edit**: Whoops, I realized that the second condition wouldn't work if there was part of the URL that was actually formatted correctly. I've changed it to be more reliable now.

Comment: Thanks a million Tim, so just to clarify, a url like mysite.com/tIM will be re-written as mysite.com/Tim?
And say there's one called mysite.com/tim stack overflow (three words with spaces), will that work too?

Comment: Yep. The edit takes care of the second part (and retains the functionality of the first part).

Comment: Tim, nothing seems to be happening, except, when I type the url without the trailing / it takes me to the homepage. Is there any chance we can interact and you can do this as a project for me? Don't worry if not, just asking.

Comment: Are your URLs exactly as you suggested? (Your comment to Pekka suggests they might be a little more complex). As far as the project goes, I'm unfortunately not in a position to do that sort of thing, although others might be willing.